# Load json data from local asset folder

Tags: android, json, spinner, adapter

I just want to ask that how to load this type of JSON data from local asset folder in android spinners, I know most parts like loading the data and all that but I am not able to iterate through the JSON

```
{"india":["delhi","mumbai"],"usa":["newyork","california"]}
```

its a short list it has more data so just tell me how to iterate in this case btw i have two spinners first should be loaded with country names and next with respective cities of that country and the second spinner should be loaded based on the selected country from first spinner..

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
JsonArray array = [your complete json];

for(int ss= 0;ss<array.size();ss++){
    JsonObject object = array.getJsonObject(ss);

    JSONArray ja = object.getJSONArray("india");

    //do whatever you want to do with ja
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'your complete json'

Comment: The complete json is very large, it contains 100 of items so

Comment: put all the JSON into:
JsonArray array = new JsonArray(String object containng json);

Answer (score 0):

this should depend on how you have defined your adapter and how you are calling this json data.

what I would personaly do is to use gson to parse this data into a POJO and store the results in an arraylist then use the adapter to loop through the arraylist

you can checkout my github repo for an example  of a spinner  https://github.com/AustineGwa/android-spinner2

Comment: pls provide me with some example as i don't know that, btw i have two spinners first should be loaded with country names and next with respective cities of that country and the second spinner should be loaded based on the selected country from first spinner..

Comment: check out my github repo for an example on using spinners with an adapter https://github.com/AustineGwa/android-spinner2

Comment: does that answer my question because the biggest problem is the loading of data as i have to load countires in spinner 1 and the cities in spinner 2

Comment: ifyou check the repo I am using an adapter to load a list of planets into a spinner so I think it can help you understand how to work around your problem

Comment: and what about that JSON data retrieval problem from the file

Comment: am working on an example now possibly I will put the link on the same repo

Comment: I have browsed the internet and I found this https://www.codementor.io/tips/1304827783/reading-json-file-from-assets-in-android-